# Save some part of livestreaming video from videoview like VLC player

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, video-capture, live-streaming

Scenario : I want to give user an option to save some part of the live streaming video from the surfaceview present in android (give him a control startSaving() and stopSaving())

I am able to display live streaming on android surfaceview by giving the url of ipcamera to it.

Now i want to save part of the live streaming in my sdcard (in any playable video format)

What i tried : i am able to get data in byte[] which is most probably mjpeg frame(dont know what format they are in), I stored them up in vector and tried converting them to a file with .mp4 extension, obviously video was corrupted as i did not encode it in any way.

So my question is how should i save it as media file(any playable format)? how should i approach this?
note: i dont want to use NDK

Thanks in advance.